Are there any mentions of gemstones in the Bhagavta purana
Edited from a previous post.
I came across the following quote,
"Bhagavata [mentions] gemstones being discovered under earth and sea."
But when I looked online I couldn't find any reference to gemstones in the same purana.
All I could find what how the purana mentions that Bali's body turned into gems after offering his head to Vishnu. Apologies if I remembered that story wrong.
Can someone please explain what he means about gemstones being found under earth and the sea, after researching I couldn't find anything in the puranas about them.
